# Tensorflow - What is wrong if mainly bias is updated?

Tags: tensorflow

I use a pre-trained network from [Tensorflow-Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/) and pass the outcoming vector through 2 fully connected layers. I initialize the weight matrices with He-initialization and the biases with 0.

The loss function is behaving strangly. Also it does update the weights matrices somewhat, but mainly the biases.

Does anybody know, how to improve the learning?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Correct classification and loss]

[image: Histogram of weights]

```
with tf.name_scope('tf_hub'):
    module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/pnasnet_large/feature_vector/2")
    tf_hub_features = module(X)  # Features with shape [batch_size, num_features].

he_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(factor=2.0, mode='FAN_IN', uniform=False)

with tf.name_scope('Hidden1'):
    W1 = tf.get_variable(initializer=he_initializer, shape=[Constants.PNAS_NET2_NB_FEATURES, config["h1_nb_units"]],
                         name="W1")
    # W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([Constants.PNAS_NET2_NB_FEATURES, config["h1_nb_units"]]), name="W1")
    tf.summary.histogram("W1", W1)
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([config["h1_nb_units"]]), name="b1")
    tf.summary.histogram("b1", b1)
    o1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_hub_features, W1) + b1, name="o1")
    # dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=o1, rate=config["keep_probability"], name="dropout1")

with tf.name_scope('Hidden2'):
    W2 = tf.get_variable(initializer=he_initializer, shape=[config["h1_nb_units"], config["h2_nb_units"]],
                         name="W2")
    tf.summary.histogram("W2", W2)
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([config["h2_nb_units"]]), name="b2")
    tf.summary.histogram("b2", b2)
    o2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(o1, W2) + b2, name="o2")

with tf.name_scope('Y'):
    WY = tf.get_variable(initializer=he_initializer, shape=[config["h2_nb_units"], config["output_dim"]],
                         name="WY")
    tf.summary.histogram("WY", WY)
    bY = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([config["output_dim"]]), name="bY")
    tf.summary.histogram("bY", bY)
    Y_star = tf.add(tf.matmul(o2, WY), bY, name="Y_star")
    Y = tf.nn.sigmoid(Y_star, name="Y")

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name="Y_")
    loss = tf.losses.log_loss(Y_, Y_hat)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config["learning_rate"])
train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. I had an error in feeding the input. They were all zeros and some ones. Therefore, there were only minor changes in the weights. I suppose the bias adjusted since it will learn something like the "mean" in linear regression.